# how can I solve for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having a bit of trouble solving for x when trying to find $f^{-1}$. I have $$y=\frac{x+5}{x-4}$$ How can I get x on one side? I tried multiplying both sides by the denominator but I am still left with an $x$ on both sides...

Comment: That was a good start! After that move the terms containing an $x$ to the other side. Remember to swap signs when appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to expand out the brackets and re-factor:

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
y & = & \frac{x+5}{x-4}\\
y(x-4) & = & x+5\\
yx-4y&=&x+5\\
yx-x &=&4y+5\\
x(y-1)&=&4y+5\\
x&=&\frac{4y+5}{y-1}
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x+5 = 1\cdot(x-4) + 9$. Just as with numbers, this means that $x-4$ divides $x+5$ once with a remainder of 9. So you can write $(x+5)/(x-4)$ as $1+\frac{9}{x-4}$. It should be easy to get $x$ on one side now.

Comment: For doing $x+5=1.(x-4)+9$, assuming $x\neq 4$ is essential. :-)

Comment: Just as with numbers, one needs to be careful when dividing by zero. Simply by paying careful attention to the statement of the problem we can see that $x=4$ could be problematic.

Comment: Usually when we are working with rational **functions**; we delete the roots of its denominator of our domain. So, what you did here is someway legal.

Answer (score 3):

First multiply out to get rid of the fraction: $y(x-4)=x+5$, or $yx-4y=x+5$. Now collect the $x$ terms on one side and everything else on the other: $yx-x=5+4y$. Factor the lefthand side: $(y-1)x=5+4y$. Now just divide both sides by $y-1$, and you’ll have $x$ in terms of $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply with the denominator:

$$y(x-4)=x+5$$
$$xy -4y=x+5$$
Take all x and bring them to the left side, all other terms to the right side.
$$xy -x = 5+4y$$
Single out x:
$$x(y-1)=5+4y$$
Divide by the factor:
$$x=\frac{5+4y}{y-1}$$

Note: $x\ne4$, because of the first equation.